# How to know, from what user cron execute task?

Tags: linux, cron

When I want to see tasks from root, it say "no crontab for root". I need to find all tasks from all users, and then I will fix bug in it (I don't know where that task is). How can I find user name?

Redhat Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the contents of `/var/spool/cron` - will provide you a list of all of the users that have cron entries.

Then you can use:

```
[root@server ~]#crontab -u username -l
```

replace the `username` , from `cron` file contents.

Comment: crontabs can also come from other places, such as /etc/crontab or /etc/crond.d/.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use a webgui take a look at [webmin](http://webmin.com/)

by default the cronjobs are stored under **/var/spool/cron/crontabs/** username